# Display the product category of a an order item in the WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, email-notifications

I am using the plugin smart coupons for Woocommerce. In trying to customize the gift certificate received by mail, I can not display the category of the product included in the order.

How to display the category of a product in the order's email?

Answer (score 2):

As `$order` *(an instance of the `WC_Order` object)* is included in most of the email templates and hooks, you can get the categories of the product included in the order. Remember that an order can have many items and each item can have many categories. You will get those product categories using the following code:

```
$product_categories = array();

// Loop through order items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $items ){
    // Get an array of the WP_Terms of the product categories
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $items->get_product_id(), 'product_cat' );

    // Loop through the product categories WP_Term objects
    foreach( $terms as $wp_term ){
        // Get the product category ID
        $term_id = $wp_term->term_id;
        // Get the product category Nmae
        $term_name = $wp_term->name;
        // Get the product category Slug
        $term_slug = $wp_term->slug;
        // Get the product category Parent ID
        $term_parent_id = $wp_term->parent;

        // Set each product category WP_Term object in an array (avoiding duplicates)
        $product_categories[$wp_term->term_id] = $wp_term;
    }
}
// Output the raw data of all product categories in the order (Testing)
var_dump($product_categories);
```

This code is tested and works.